# Push Notification at Dynamic Time

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, backend

I am trying to make a simple, cross-platform task management app. I have my tasks stored as Parse objects and they each have date/time properties. I would like a user to get a notification on all their devices at that time for each task. Is there a way to do this? I can use REST API calls from each mobile app to schedule a push notification, but if a user modifies or deletes the task, Parse provides no way to modify or delete the scheduled task.

Essentially, how can I trigger a push notification at a time that can be changed. I am fine with a solution that does not use Parse (e.g. it can involve code on my own website/server, or another backend service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [cloud code background job](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs) and [scheduling](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-scheduling). You'll need to create a job that searches for tasks that need to have a notification sent, send it, and then mark the task with some sort of "sent" flag so it's not sent again. You could either have this flagged on the task itself, or create your own notification object that is associated with the task, so if the task gets updated you can also update your notification object.

You will also need to then schedule the task. You could get it to repeat every minute, but this may be overkill depending on the granularity of the task scheduling you give to the users.

Comment: Thanks! So, it says I can schedule jobs for a future time (presumably from the Parse.com console), but is it possible to set up a recurring a job? If I understand you correctly, the whole job would have to run once a minutes (or some preferred interval). Is it possible to schedule a job to run once every minute for 24/7?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. All you do is set your initial start date, and then setup the repeat schedule for every minute, after 00:00.